# What is best tool to get EXIF data?

Tags: image, image-processing, exif

I am looking for backend best tool to retrieve Exif data of images. There are various tool and even function are provided  for some  programming languages to get Exif data, but they  are not reliable.

What is the best tool on the web to retrieve Exif data that work with various camera manufacturers?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Perl module Image::EXIF

https://metacpan.org/pod/Image::EXIF